# server can't find 2.0.9.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, nslookup, vpc-peering

I have set up a VPC peering between two different project's VPC on GCP and it works fine when i ping my vm-instance and i'm also able to ssh to my instance with private ips. 
However, if I query it for reverse dns from one vm-instance to another instance with nslookup, it throws error;
server can't find 2.0.9.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

my arp doesn't show connected devices either just one ip for router i believe, i get the same status: NXDOMAIN when i dig 10.9.0.2

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The private-network address ranges usually don't have reverse DNS.  If you run your own DNS server you can add them, and even point names back to proper host names on your private network.  Alternatively, there MIGHT be a GCP based dns server that does have rDNS set up for the 10./8 network space....

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm relatively new to these things. Call me a novice but actually, I had done the same thing (peering VPC from different accounts) on AWSes cloud and I was able to query reverse DNS, connect via ssh and my ARP would show the visited nodes. Am I missing something here other than configuring my own DNS server?

Comment: Seems to me that would indicate that AWS has reverse DNS set up for whatever RFC1918 addresses they use in whatever DNS server they point the VMs to...

Comment: Thanks for your input, can you show me how do I go about setting up my DNS server to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc-peering#no_compute_engine_dns_across_projects), "Compute Engine internal DNS names created in a network are not accessible to peered networks. The IP address of the VM should be used to reach the VM instances in peered network."

You may check the documentation links [1][2] for more information.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/#vpc_networks_and_subnets

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/#instancenames